# Saml Inter service provider authentication

Tags: java, saml, opensaml

In our application we have two service providers one Idp. Our client is mobile application. One service provider(A) is deployed in cloud and another one(B) is behind firewall. But Service provider (A) is allowed to access Service provider (B) via NAT/ restricted IP Access.

My Problem is i want enable SSO (SAML). Give me some details and How can i enable inter service provider authentication.

Comment: Your talking about a Idp is this a SAML idp or just a ldap or AD server